# How do I download a tarball from GitHub using cURL?

Tags: linux, curl, github, wget

I am trying to download a tarball from GitHub using [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL), but it does not seem to be redirecting:

```
$ curl --insecure https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs/tarball/v0.24-beta2
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://nodeload.github.com/pinard/Pymacs/tarball/v0.24-beta2">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Note: wget works for me:

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs/tarball/v0.24-beta2
```

However I want to use cURL because ultimately I want to untar it inline with something like:

```
$ curl --insecure https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs/tarball/v0.24-beta2 | tar zx
```

I found that the URL after redirecting turned out to be https://download.github.com/pinard-Pymacs-v0.24-beta1-0-gcebc80b.tar.gz, but I would like cURL to be smart enough to figure this out.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Use the `-L` option to follow redirects:

```
curl -L https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs/tarball/v0.24-beta2 | tar zx
```

Comment: For `https`, you'll also likely need `-k`.

Comment: Why lately there are certificates problems on raw.github.com? I had problems to install homebrew and rvm on a new machine. I used to copy and paste from the homepage and was working. Now I get the certificate problem: 

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"..

If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.

Comment: Mmmm ... is there a possibility to include the sub-modules in the tarball as well? It seems, that for sub-modules only empty directories are created in the tarball.

Comment: Not sure if this is a temporary problem right now, but github is returning a 500 internal server error for this at the moment.

Comment: And just to potentially save someone a google, `-L` means follow redirects.

Comment: this unzips to a funky directory.  possible to name that directory?  Even better name it the version that was downloaded.

Comment: wont this just download the html page that hosts the file?

Answer (score 50):

The modernized way of doing this is:

```
curl -sL https://github.com/user-or-org/repo/archive/sha1-or-ref.tar.gz | tar xz
```

Replace `user-or-org`, `repo`, and `sha1-or-ref` accordingly.

If you want a zip file instead of a tarball, specify `.zip` instead of `.tar.gz` suffix.

You can also retrieve the archive of a private repo, by specifying `-u token:x-oauth-basic` option to curl. Replace `token` with a [personal access token.](https://github.com/settings/tokens)

Comment: of all the answers, this was exactly what i was looking for!  If you have an oauth token you can use that directly; `https://token@github.com/user-or-org/repo/archive/sha1-or-ref.tar.gz`

Comment: how would this work for downloading from releases instead of archives?

Comment: @waspinator , I use `curl -OL https://github.com/user-or-org/repo/releases/download/version/<asset name>.tar.gz`
See example [here](https://github.com/fomightez/gohugo-binder/blob/4713e967d083fc00f120b08715855912f52d6a61/postBuild#L49)

Comment: Can you explain how this is better than the accepted answer?

Comment: Maybe because `.../tarball/...` method only produces tar.gz? GH added a more flexible method later that allows you extract archive in format you want based on suffix `.tar.gz` or `.zip`. I don't remember any more why I wrote this post.

Answer (score 14):

You can also use wget to »untar it inline«. Simply specify stdout as the output file (`-O -`):

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs/tarball/v0.24-beta2 -O - | tar xz
```

Answer (score 3):

All the other solutions require specifying a release/version number which obviously breaks automation.

This solution- *currently tested and known to work with **Github API v3***- however can be used programmatically to grab the **LATEST** release without specifying any tag or release number and un-TARs the binary to an arbitrary name you specify in switch `--one-top-level="pi-ap"`.  Just swap-out user ***f1linux*** and repo ***pi-ap*** in below example with your own details and Bob's your uncle:

```
curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/f1linux/pi-ap/tarball | tar xzvf - --one-top-level="pi-ap" --strip-components 1
```

Comment: This is beautiful, but could really use some explanation. e.g. which GitHub API version is this and where is it documented?

Comment: @l3l_aze  Just edited the answer it include the current Githib API version number my solution is tested and known to work with.  Thanks for your feedback!- T

Comment: Whoa. I didn't think this could possibly get better than what you'd already shared. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

with a specific dir:

```
cd your_dir && curl -L https://download.calibre-ebook.com/3.19.0/calibre-3.19.0-x86_64.txz | tar zx
```

Comment: more better way   ```cd your_dir && curl -L https://download.calibre-ebook.com/3.19.0/calibre-3.19.0-x86_64.txz | tar zx; cd -```

Comment: There's no need to cd at all, tar has the `--directory` option to do that for you.  So: `curl --location https://download.calibre-ebook.com/3.19.0/calibre-3.19.0-x86_64.txz | tar --extract --xz --directory your_dir`