# Cloning the CodeIgniter framework to build my website

Tags: git, codeigniter, github

Coming from an SVN background Git is really taking some time to get used to. I really enjoy it, but I'm still trying to figure out how to use it in different situations. So here is my question:

My PHP framework of choice is CodeIgniter. I plan on building my personal website off of CI and I was thinking the best way to do this would be to clone CI and build my website.  I'd be doing this because I really want a super easy way to update the CI framework.  I'm just not sure if this is really the right way to use cloning or if there is another tactic I should be taking.  I was looking into submodules a little bit, but that doesn't really seem to be the correct way to go either.  Help?

Comment: What you want is a good deploy method, which has already been [answered very well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git) - at least I do not know of any better solution.

Comment: “to clone CI and build my website” What do you mean, you want to add your code to the CI repository?

Comment: No, I don't want to add my code to the CI repo.  I really want it to be a one way relationship.  I want my site to be built using CI and I would like to be able to pull updates into my site as CI updates, but I'm never going to do a pull request.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I did not really understand Git/GitHub, this question was poorly asked on my part.  I was considering just deleting it, but I think my answer here might just help other SVN developers who are starting to venture into Git/GitHub.

Basically, I want to work with CodeIgniter and be able to pull in updates from the CI Master Branch.  The workflow that I need is very simple:  Fork CI and Branch my fork to create my own personal websites.  By doing this, I can pull in updates from the upstream CI branch, keeping my framework codebase up-to-date.

Branching is so crappy in SVN that just the concept of branching with Git seemed insane, now that I understand more about Git, I realize that branching is all I really needed.  Duh.  Anyway, hope this helps anyone coming from SVN.  Branching is dead simple and fast in Git...don't over-think it.

Comment: This is exactly what I came here to ask, but want to work this way with BitBucket. Thanks for asking, and explaining your finding!

Answer (score 1):

Considering that [CodeIgniter has a GitHub repo](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter), sure, you can clone it directly in your server, at the place mentioned by the [Installation page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html).
Although for pure deployment purpose (i.e. for a code base I won't make any updates to, and won't push back to a remote repo, I prefer [downloading an archive from the tarballs provided by GitHub for each project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746325/how-do-i-download-a-tarball-from-github-using-curl)).

But that should be separate from your project (with your views, controllers, models, ... from your "application"), which should be in a separate bare repo on the same server, and cloned locally on your workstation.
Then, the [deployment method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git) mentioned by [Lars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898999/lars) in the comment takes care of the rest.

Comment: SO what you're saying is clone CodeIgniter and fork my CI repo to build my website?

Comment: @JoeC: no, CI is just a *framework* you don't need to fiddle with. You just need a copy on your server. What you need as a separate project (and separate Git repo) is your own CI *application* that will need to be deployed on the same server within the CI framework, in order to be visible.