# setting the work-tree of each bare repo

Tags: git

As you can see below I have to set the work-tree of a bare repo:

```
cd barerepo
git status
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree

git --work-tree=/var/www/mywork/ status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

How do I set the work-tree for that repo so that I don't have to specify it everytime?

I tried modifying `barerepo/config` with this but it doesn't work.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
    worktree = /var/www/mywork
```

Answer (score 18):

Bare repos are not supposed to have a work tree, so git prints the "fatal: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense" error message. Therefore, you need to set `bare = false` in the repo's config file.

```
user@host:~$ cd barerepo
user@host:~/barerepo$ git config --bool core.bare false
user@host:~/barerepo$ git config --path core.worktree /var/www/mywork
```

However, if barerepo did not previously exist, you should use this command instead:

```
git init --separate-git-dir=. /var/www/mywork
```

This command will also create a `.git` file in the work tree pointing to the git dir:

```
gitdir: /home/user/barerepo
```

Comment: @PineappleUndertheSea: good question. :) You'll have an empty index, so the next commit would delete everything from the current branch. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16582931/1479945

Answer (score 5):

Note that the question and answers are from year 2012, but since git 2.5, even with a bare repository you can create separate worktrees with:

```
$ git worktree add /var/www/mywork/ master
$ git worktree add /var/www/workdev/ devel
```

See [git-worktree(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).

It will not change `core.worktree` but create a `worktrees` directory in your git repository.

You may want to change the configuration option `extensions.worktreeConfig` to true if you don't want all the worktrees and the bare repository to share the same config.

Comment: Adding worktrees is completely different from moving the main worktree. A bare repo can have these side worktrees because they're just intended as scratch pad locations, but it cannot, by definition, have a main worktree which is what core.worktree does.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the proposed solution (2012, pre Git 2.5 which will be released in July 2015) would *not* work directly with `git config` command.
It would keep dying with a:

```
fatal: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense.
```

That is what Git 2.5 (July 2015) will address:

See [commit fada767](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fada767463b599951b37bd544379a1d18dcf9370) (29 May 2015) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 103b6f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/103b6f9c2b2bbafdbde694f9390fb203f70977f0), 16 Jun 2015)</sup>

> ### `setup_git_directory`: delay `core.bare`/`core.worktree` errors
>
> If both `core.bare` and `core.worktree` are set, we complain
>   about the bogus config and die.
>   Dying is good, because it
>   avoids commands running and doing damage in a potentially
>   incorrect setup.
>   But dying *there* is bad, because it means
>   that commands which do not even care about the work tree
>   cannot run.
>   **This can make repairing the situation harder**:

```
  [setup]
  $ git config core.bare true
  $ git config core.worktree /some/path

  [OK, expected.]
  $ git status
  fatal: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense

  [Hrm...]
  $ git config --unset core.worktree
  fatal: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense

  [Nope...]
  $ git config --edit
  fatal: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense

  [Gaaah.]
  $ git help config
  fatal: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense
```

> Instead, **let's issue a warning about the bogus config when
>   we notice it (i.e., for all commands), but only die when the
>   command tries to use the work tree (by calling setup_work_tree).**
>
> So we now get:

```
$ git status
warning: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense
fatal: unable to set up work tree using invalid config

$ git config --unset core.worktree
warning: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense
```