# Setting up a git deployment process to ec2

Tags: git, ssh, amazon-ec2, deployment

I followed [this tutorial](http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2015/03/28/automating-deployment-with-git/): on setting up a git deployment process to an `ec2` instance.

I carefully went through all the steps of ssh'ing into the `ec2` machine with a `~/.ssh/` host in the config file.  Creating the bare git repo. Adding the `post-receive` hook script and so on.

Locally, I make some changes, commit.
Then I added the `ec2` repo with `git remote add deploy ec2:/home/ec2-user/ab-site` (ab-site is the bare git repo I just initialized -- and `ec2` is the ssh alias I set up locally in the `~/.ssh/config` file).

Yet When I go to push with `git push deploy +master:refs/heads/master`

I get a bunch of errors.

```
warning: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense remote:
warning: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense remote: error:
insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database
./objects remote: fatal: failed to write object error: unpack failed:
unpack-objects abnormal exit
```

So I'm curious what I should look at next to fix this.

Comment: "insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database" — this part of the error message is telling. I would start by checking to make sure that your ec2 user (in this case probably `ubuntu`) has permissions to write to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

> core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense

That is a warning which, [since Git 2.5+, is fixable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30927302/6309). If that warning is on the remote side, that means core.bare was set to true, while worktree was set as well.

The usual fix is `git config --unset core.worktree` but in your case, [from that comment](http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2015/03/28/automating-deployment-with-git/#comment-3298249896)

> with `bare=false` it works OK.

Then you can double check the permission issue.

Comment: My understanding of all this was that I was creating a `bare` git repo as these are the only kinds of repos that one can push to.  Since my goal is to push my website to my server and run a deployment script on the push receive hook, this seemed to make sense.  But now I should set bare equal to false?  Sure, I can take the advice but I have no understanding of why.

Comment: @AlexBollbach I agree: I would unset the worktree instead, and keep the bare nature. Note that, since Git 2.3, you can push too non-bare repos, as I mention in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44406425/6309 (see the links there)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem contains warnings and errors

1. Warning of

   warning: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense remote:
   warning: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense remote: error:

**Solution**

Bare repository are read only repository. The most common use case for bare repo is to create a remote central Git repository ,

so git prints the "fatal: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense" error message. Therefore, you need to set `bare = false` in the repo's config file.

```
cd barerepo
git config --bool core.bare false
git config --path core.worktree /var/www/mywork
```

2. Error of

   Insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database

   ./objects remote: fatal: failed to write object error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit

**Solution**

```
cd repository/.git

sudo chmod -R g+ws *
sudo chgrp -R mygroup *

git config core.sharedRepository true
```