# Clone a git repository and keep unreachable commits

Tags: git

Is there a way to clone a remote git repo while keeping any unreachable commits that may be in that repo?

The scenario is this: I need to recover a branch that was deleted from a bare git repo on a server that I maintain. I have the hash of the last commit to this branch, but The regular git commands do not seem to be able to function on bare repos, so as far as I am aware there is not any way I can recover it directly on the server.

I also do not have access to any non-bare repos that contain this commit. If I did, I could recover it easily by checking out the commit hash and then creating a branch from it. This is why I would like to be able to clone this repo while keeping any unreachable commits in it, so I can do exactly that.

Comment: For what it's worth, many (not all) git commands *do* work on bare repos, e.g., you can `git show <commit-ID>`, `git branch <commit-ID>`, etc.  The `git branch` method would be the quickest way to fix the problem, assuming the commit is still actually there.

Comment: @torek I had already fixed my problem, but I tried this out anyway. It does work! The exact syntax I used was `git branch <branch-name> <commit-hash>`. This form of the command evidently works fine on bare repos. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is:

1. Copy the bare repo to another folder using normal file copy commands.
2. [Convert the bare repo copy to a normal repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637378/how-do-i-convert-a-bare-git-repository-into-a-normal-one-in-place).
3. Do what you need to do to locate the commit object you seek.
4. Create a new branch at the lost commit once its located.
5. Add the original bare repo as a remote.
6. Push the new branch up to the bare repository.

Comment: Hi, I don't maintain the server (BitBucket), but I really need to get to an orphaned commit. This commit was on a branch that nobody has a copy of. I can see it in BB, but cannot fetch it or clone it. Please help =)

Comment: If you can see the commit, then you know its hash. You can fetch it using `git fetch origin <commitHash>:refs/remotes/origin/orphaned-commit`

Comment: @Carl the "git fetch origin..." command worked for me with GitHub, you should probably add to your answer!