# How do I test a local Git branch on the remote Git server, when the local branch does not exist on the remote server, no merge with the origin/master?

Tags: git, version-control, workflow

I am working on a web application and the Git repository is remote.  I created it on the server with:

```
git init --bare --shared /var/www/dev/repo.git
```

I issued `git clone user@myserver:/var/www/dev/repo.git` on my development machine.

If I create a new branch on my local machine, how do I test it on the server?

I have Apache (on Debian) pointing to `/var/www/dev/repo.git`.  If I checkout a new branch, test, that branch is all local.  When I have completed my test, I do not want to merge my test and then push to origin/master to see the test branch.  That defeats the purpose of the local branch and testing.

- Do I create the test branch on the remote also?
- How do I make the server use the test branch and allow me switch back at will, as many developers could make a change?

Not sure of the workflow here.  I wanted to be able to collaborate and say, ok, refresh the page, and they'd see it.  Don't like it?  We switch back to master *on the server* and Apache is still pointing to the same set of file *names*, minus the changes to the internal files.  I can then delete the feature or design change which was rejected.

EDIT:  It sounds like I should have went with `git init`.  I have lots of source code, and I thought I would put it in the bare repository.  I read more after answers (thank you) and see `--bare` does not hold any code I can point Apache too, so I don't see how anyone views the final product.

Nevertheless, I think this only makes the question a little different.  How do I test a branch of existing code I started with `git init` on the server and am working with a `git clone` of on my development machine?  Do I simply create another directory Apache knows about to push my change/fix/feature to and test?  The only thing I can think of is to have many different virtual directories or sub domains for a developer which each member can get to.  That doesn't sound very "*Gitty*" though.

Answer (score 1):

If you created the repository with `--bare`, you will only have the version history of the repository in it, **no working copy**. This means that the Apache won't be able to serve the site. You will have to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10637882/3638220) to get a full repository.

Once you have done that, on your local machine run:

```
git push origin <dev-branch>
```

Then on the server:

```
git fetch
git checkout <dev-branch>
```

To get back on master:

```
git checkout master
```

Note: git, by default, doesn't allow you push to the remote's currently checked out branch, in a non-bare repository. This means you will either have to `git checkout master` on the server before pushing or, on the server, run:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch warn
```

**However**, an alternative, and likely more productive, workflow is set up your local development environment and use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) or similar to securely expose your `localhost` to the internet and share that link.

Comment: That does not sound like it is the way I should be doing things, as in you're right about the way, but it doesn't feel right that I should be doing this at all.  I should have used init I think.  See edit.

Comment: If you started with a non-bare repository, and cloned it to your local machine, everything _after_ the first paragraph is still relevant.