# How to commit a git repository inside another git repository

Tags: git, github, commit, git-submodules

I'm developing an application that uses git, so I need to test its integration with git. Inside my git repository, I need to have another repository (my_git_repo/tests/another_repo). How can I commit it without git submodules? (I don't want to have another remote repository (in github/bitbucket, etc) for just one file)

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems like it would be easier to just avoid the entire problem. Could you test the integration by not merely using an existing repository, but by setting up the repository from scratch? That is, make the test start with `mkdir`, `git init`, etc. This would avoid the need to track the sub-repository entirely.

Comment: this is my current workarround, but I prefer to avoid these steps to avoid complexity (because i need to do some edits and create some commits)

Comment: I think @hvd is right because if you commit this second repository, your changes to it will accumulate and have a side-effect. If you always create it from scratch you will have a reproduceable build, which is a good thing.

Comment: You could include an already set up sub-repository as a zip file -- or whatever other format you prefer -- and then make your test create or clear a directory and simply unzip the sub-repository there. That said, while it greatly reduces the complexity of running the tests, it greatly increases the complexity of creating and maintaining the tests, so it's not something I recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Submodules don't necessarily need to be cloned separately; you can publish a project and its submodules in a single repo. Just have a branch dedicated to the submodule contents in your main repo, then after cloning the main repo `git clone -sb` the submodule directly from there.

```
# setup your current repo this way:
( git init sub
  cd sub
  > file
  git add .
  git commit -m-
  git remote add origin ..
  git push -u origin master:sub/master
)
```

Setup in new clone:

```
git branch -t sub/master origin/sub/master
git clone -sb sub/master . sub
```

and `sub` will have the most recent content.

`git rev-parse :sub` will show you what's committed for `sub` -- i.e. what should be checked out there -- when you don't just want the current branch tip.

You could hook up the `git submodule` command here, with a `.gitmodules` file and this and that, but it hardly seems worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I loved @hvd's reply and I think it should be an answer that deserves voting up:

> You could include an already set up sub-repository as a zip file -- or whatever other format you prefer -- and then make your test create or clear a directory and simply unzip the sub-repository there. That said, while it greatly reduces the complexity of running the tests, it greatly increases the complexity of creating and maintaining the tests, so it's not something I recommend.

There are situations sub-modules are just too complex for a simple issue. My code was already working with the setup similar to the original question. My problem was involving test repos where those repos (3 of them) were going to be used for testing purposes only using actual repos with known commits. So I wanted to add those repos into git just like any other subfolder without the complexity of submodules... this is for testing for crying out loud. I needed the histories to be within those test repos. I noticed that the complexity of submodules is actually greater than the said 'complexity of creating and maintaining the tests'... actually it's simple.

```
const GitMockReposWD = Path.resolve(__dirname, 'mocks/git')
before(`Decompress git mock repos...`, function (done) {
  if (!Fs.existsSync(GitMockReposWD)) {
    console.log(`Decompressing git mock repos...`)
    const Decompress = require('decompress')
    Decompress(Path.resolve(__dirname, 'mocks/git-mock-repos.zip'), GitMockReposWD).then(() => {
      console.log('Done decompressing!')
      done()
    })
  } else {
    console.log(`git mock repos already exist...`)
    done()
  }
})
after(`Clean git mock repos...`, function () {
  if (Fs.existsSync(GitMockReposWD)) {
    console.log(`Cleaning git mock repos...`);
    Fs.rmdir(GitMockReposWD, () => {
      console.log(`Done cleaning git mock repos!`)
    })
  }
})
```

The above code simply decompresses the test repos before the tests suites are run and cleans them up afterwards. The idea here is to setup the repos as required by your scenario and then add them to an archive. If there are any changes to the repos then you just update the archive.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform your nested repository into a bare repo. A bare repository can be committed inside another repository.

One way (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637378/how-do-i-convert-a-bare-git-repository-into-a-normal-one-in-place)) to transform a repository into a bare repository:

```
git clone --bare test-repo 
cd test-repo.git # directory created by previous command
git remote rm origin # to remove the pointer to your original repo
```

Now, `test-repo.git` can be committed inside your main repository. If, at some point, you'd like to make edits in your test repository (edit files, add commits) you can just clone it back into a non-bare repo (`git clone test-repo.git`).