# How to restore the project if I have only .git folder?

Tags: git

How to restore my project? I save only /.git folder and now need to restore project from this folder.

Comment: If you `cd` to that folder and type `git status` from the bash, what do you see?  I think your situation should be fixable.

Comment: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recovering codebase from bare git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775995/recovering-codebase-from-bare-git-repository)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637378/how-do-i-convert-a-bare-git-repository-into-a-normal-one-in-place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. If you previously committed files to git:**

First, try to do a `git log`. Then you will see the commits. If you see a commit that makes sense, you can do `git checkout <HASH>`. Where Hash is the commit hash.

Then check to see if yours files exits.

**2. If it is only local changes that you have not committed**:

You can do a `git status` to see the changes. A `git stash` will stash these changes temporarily and a `git stash pop` will re-apply the changes.

***NOTE: THE FOLLOWING IS A DESTRUCTIVE GIT PROCESS BUYER BEWARE***

You can do a `git reset --HARD <HASH>` and then a `git push -f` to force push the working code up to your repo eliminating your mistaken commit but also eliminating all other commits after the hash.

It is much better to `git revert <HASH>` and then a `git push`. This will show the reverting process in your git history and preserve all states. `git push -f` is not something you should take lightly as it can cause you much pain.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662104/git-how-to-restore-a-repo-from-a-single-git-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1 has an answer that worked for me. git clone .git some-directory

Answer (score 2):

Got to the same situation today -- trying to restore the whole project from only the saved `/.git` folder, and it turns out to be really simple and straightforward:

1. Create a folder and expand the saved `.git` into folder.
2. Do `git status`, and I see every single one of my files is reported as `deleted`
3. Just do `git reset --hard`, and
4. Voila, every single of my files is now restored.