# Git: How to restore a repo from a single .git folder

Tags: git

I've got my hands on a `.git` folder from a GitLab server that crashed.
I need to restore this repo from this lone `.git` folder.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

Just clone from the `.git` folder

```
git clone .git my-repo
```

Comment: I've had success running `git init` next to this `.git` dir, but this looks better.