# How to export project from .git folder

Tags: git

Usually, when I want to clone a project, I get a `git link` which I then use to clone the project. This time I got a `.git` folder that holds all information about repository - branches, hooks ect. As I understand, I can easily extract the project from this folder (clone it). How one can do that? I use GitKraken and SourceTree.

Comment: If I have understood your problem correctly then what you can try doing is `git log` from you command line which will show you the history. Then you can copy the hash that you need and revert back to that point using `git reset --hard <commit hash>`.

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya This is new project by someone else. I just want to get project and compile it to test it.

Comment: would you like to export to another repo server?

Comment: I would like to export locally on my machine. Basically, I want to get to the project content.

Comment: Yes @PeteWonder, if the `.git` folder has everything then you will be getting all the files in your local machine using the `git reset --hard <commit hash>`. Can you try this?

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya Worked, thanks. Please repost this suggestion as answer, so I can approve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore the project if I have only .git folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676370/how-to-restore-the-project-if-i-have-only-git-folder)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22only+.git+folder%22

Comment: `git checkout master`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can try doing is

> git log

from you command line which will show you the history. Then you can copy the hash that you need and revert back to that point using

> git reset --hard ~commit hash~