# Git Is there a possibility to restore delete files just from .git folder?

Tags: git

I deleted git repo from github and don't have my code anymore locally. The only thing I have left is .git folder. Can I restore files just with this folder? :((

Comment: Try `git checkout -f HEAD` or you're out of luck.

Comment: Ok I did that, what to do next?

Comment: Do you see your files in the directory where `.git` resides? (i.e. the parent directory of `.git`)

Comment: Seems like your question is already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676390/9703609

Comment: Sure! No problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.git` directory is left intact, you can use `git checkout -f HEAD` to restore all files from the current commit. This will overwrite any existing files.

If nothing shows up after running `git checkout -f HEAD`, try looking for branches and commits with `git branch -v` and `git reflog` and see if you recognize anything. Do `git checkout -f <hash>` where `<hash>` is the commit hash that you see from previous Git output.