# Recover project source code from .git directory

Tags: git

What are the steps to recover the source code from a .git directory containing objects and packfiles? How to configure the config file so it becomes just a local repository?

Comment: Is the code already there or has it been deleted?  If it's been deleted can you check out another copy?

Comment: Wow, what a swift answer! All the code is there fortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .git repository is named a bare repository.
You can do what you want with this command :

```
git --git-dir=path_to_bare_repo.git archive HEAD | tar -x -C path_to_destination_dir
```

If you only want to convert a bare repository into a normal git repository, just follow the few steps of this link :
[How do I convert a bare git repository into a normal one (in-place)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637378/how-do-i-convert-a-bare-git-repository-into-a-normal-one-in-place)

Operations are pretty simple :

```
mkdir repo_dir
mv path_to_bare_repo.git repo_dir/.git
cd repo_dir/.git
git config --local --bool core.bare false
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This did it: "git --git-dir=path_to_bare_repo.git archive HEAD | tar -x -C path_to_destination_dir"

Answer (score 2):

If this was a normal repository whose working directory got deleted, simply checkout what you want while in the parent of the .git directory, e.g. `git checkout master`.

If it was a bare repository (i.e. it was your git server), then clone it into another directory with `git clone <path to .git directory>`.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have access to the git server anymore. Do I need to extract the packfiles before the checkout process?

Comment: No, git will take care of that for you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It's a normal repository, but "git checkout master" only prints "Already on 'master' Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'."

Comment: OK, then do `git checkout master .`