# npm: install module with repo data

Tags: git, version-control, npm-install

How can I install github project into `./node_modules/` so that `./node_modules/project` folder will contain `.git` subfolder?

I have tried:

```
 npm install git+https://github.com/user/project
```

but `.git/` subfolder was missed in the target `./node_modules/project/` folder.

Probably there is some other way to develop other modules (from other repos) from main application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need it, you could add the `.git` folder after the npm installation:

```
cd ./node_modules/project/
git clone --bare https://github.com/user/project .git
cd .git
git config --local --bool core.bare false
```

That is using a [bare clone that you transform into a regular repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10637882/6309).