# "git fetch" remote refs of remotes

Tags: git

I would like to be able to move all work-in-progress branches from repository to repository and be able to delete the old ones without losing any commits. Is there a way I can fetch the remote branches from a remote repository?

```
# A: Create a repo with two branches
> mkdir a ; cd a ; git init
> echo initial > file_master ; git add file_master ; git commit -am "initial"
> git checkout -b mybranch
> echo test > file_mybranch ; git add file_mybranch ; git commit -am "test"
> git checkout master

# B: Clone
> git clone . ../b ; cd ../b
> git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/mybranch
# if I wanted, I could delete a and checkout remotes/origin/mybranch

# C: Clone of clone, but it's missing mybranch
> git clone . ../c ; cd ../c
> git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
# no remotes/origin/mybranch - it's a remote of origin
# if I delete a and b I lose mybranch for good

>git ls-remote
7505fa4ec342ff85095737d27df0a5062c53d4d5        HEAD
7505fa4ec342ff85095737d27df0a5062c53d4d5        refs/heads/master
7505fa4ec342ff85095737d27df0a5062c53d4d5        refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
7505fa4ec342ff85095737d27df0a5062c53d4d5        refs/remotes/origin/master
dfd057c18baa4227905999b32bffdecf639185f7        refs/remotes/origin/mybranch
# there it is, but I don't have it locally
```

Just to reiterate, in repository **B** I can safely `rm -rf ../a`, then `git checkout remotes/origin/mybranch` and I'll have `file_mybranch`. What I want is to have this commit in repository **C**. My question is: *how can I get the branch `remotes/origin/mybranch` from **B** into **C** along with the commits it points to?* Lets say I've already deleted **A**.

Comment: Be clearer with your question because 'git fetch' already fetch all the remote branches and put them in your repository (each one prefixed by the name of the remote, here 'origin'). No need to extend the command.

Comment: I don't just want the remote branches, I want the remotes of the remote, which have already been fetched. I updated the question and do not believe it's a dupe.

Answer (score 4):

There is clearly a serious Git Naming Problem here because this problem trips people up *all the time*.  The fundamental issue is that the word "branch" is confusing.  It doesn't mean what you think it does!  See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

#### A clone is a deliberately imperfect copy

When you clone a repository using `git clone <url>` or `git clone <path>` or similar, you don't get an exact copy of the upstream repository.  You get, instead, a copy with some deliberate changes:

- The new copy has a *remote*, usually named `origin`, set to hold the URL of the original.
- The new copy takes all the *branches* from the original, but none of its *remote-tracking branches*.  Despite the name "remote-tracking branch", these things are **not** branches!  Git could call them "elephants" and it would probably be less confusing. :-) Let's call them *RTBs* here, just so that they do not have the word "branch" in them.
- The new copy starts out, in fact, with *no branches at all*, but then immediately does the equivalent of `git checkout somebranch`.  The name `git clone` gives to this `git checkout` command depends on several somewhat tricky things.
- The new clone *does* start out with a bunch of RTBs.  These are not branches, remember.  They're these funny RTB things.  RTBs are names that start with the same string as the remote, and then have a slash.

The specific *set* of RTBs you get depends on what *branches* there are in the repository you're cloning.  Let's say that the repository you're cloning has three actual branches, named `master`, `develop`, and `mybranch`.  This means you get, in your clone-imperfect-copy, three of these RTB thingies (which aren't branches), named `origin/master`, `origin/develop`, and `origin/mybranch`.

#### The `git checkout` command will *create* branches automatically

Let's say you have a repository that has no branches at all, like one of the ones made by `git clone`, and you pick a branch name out of a hat-full of possible names: `master`, `develop`, and `mybranch`.  For the sake of realism, let's use the one Git usually picks, `master`.  You convince your `git clone` command to pass this name to `git checkout`:

```
git checkout master
```

Now, the thing is, there *is no `master` branch* because there are no branches at all.  So Git can't possibly check it out.  But—this is the first tricky part—your Git *can* scan through all your RTBs, looking for one whose name *resembles* `master`.  And there it is: `origin/master` smells enough like `master`, that your Git goes and *creates* a *new* branch in your copy, called `master`, using `origin/master` as the hash ID for this new branch.

That's the final step of `git clone`: it checks out some branch, and winds up *creating* that branch in the process.  You can choose which branch, using `-b`, but you *only get one name:* you can have your Git run `git checkout master`, or you can have your Git run `git checkout mybranch`, but you cannot have it run both.  You only get one!

If you don't give a `-b` argument, your Git picks one out of the hat-full of branch names it saw on the other Git.  It usually picks `master`, but there are rules by which the *other* Git gives your Git a hint which name to pick.  The most important rule is that your Git asks the other Git which branch *it* has checked-out (or more precisely, inspects its `HEAD` setting).

#### There are ways to make a more-perfect clone, but then you can't *use* it

If you use `git clone --mirror`, you will get a perfect copy.  The problem is that this perfect copy has no work-tree: it's what Git calls a "bare" clone.

The reason for this is that such a clone is set up to be a slavish copy *all the time*: every time you run `git fetch` in the mirror clone, you update it to exactly match whatever is in the other repository.  This means you throw away any work being done on any branch, and slavishly match the other repository's branches again.  To make sure you don't *lose* work this way, Git prevents you from *doing* work in the exact-copy.

#### The solution is to put up with the imperfections

When you clone, you get that imperfect copy, and your Git checks out one branch, copying it from the RTBs your Git made by *renaming* all of their branches.

You can now run `git checkout` on each of those remaining RTBs—all but the one that `git clone` already ran `git checkout` on, that is.  The easiest thing is to just run it on all the names: it doesn't hurt to run `git checkout master` again, after all.

To extract all the names, you can use `git for-each-ref` (meant for scripting) or `git branch -r` (not so much).  You will have to massage the names a bit to strip off the `origin/` part, and run `git checkout`.

(Or, you can simply not bother to check them out until you need them.  Don't re-clone the imperfect copy: re-clone the original—assuming you still have and can reach it.)

If you still have the copy, but not the original, and want a second copy that's *exactly* like the first copy—down to having the same branches and the same RTBs—you need to use one or more tricks, because Git is not set up to do that.  One trick is to make a mirror clone anyway:

```
$ git clone --mirror url-of-copy mirror-clone-dir
```

Now you have an exact duplicate of the copy, except that your duplicate itself is a bare clone.  You can now convert it from a bare clone to a non-bare clone (see, e.g., [How do I convert a bare git repository into a normal one (in-place)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10637378/1256452)), but you should also update its `remote.origin.fetch` setting:

```
$ cd mirror-clone-dir
$ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
+refs/*:refs/*
$ git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

(and then the rest of the conversion).  Or, you can start with a normal clone, but then run one more command:

```
$ git clone <url-of-copy> new-clone-dir
[the usual messages]
$ cd new-clone-dir
$ git fetch origin '+refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

Note that this last step will *replace* all your existing remote-tracking branches ("RTBs") with the copy's remote-tracking branches.  In other words, you lose the memory of the *copy*'s branches, replacing your Git's "memory of what I saw in url-of-copy" with "memory of what I got from url-of-copy that *they* had listed as *their* memory of what *they* saw in *their* original."

You literally cannot get both, at least not using *these* RTBs: either you have your branches and remember their branches, or you have your branches and remember their memory of someone else's branches.  You do have some additional alternatives, though:

- If the real original still lives, add it as second remote, and fetch from it:

  ```
  $ git remote add real-source <url>
  $ git fetch real-source
  ```

  Now you have not just `origin/master` but also `real-source/master`.
- If not, add the *copy* as a second remote—there's no harm in having two names for the same repository—and then use the same `git fetch` trick to populate the additional set of RTBs from the copy:

  ```
  $ git remote add r2 <url-of-copy>
  $ git fetch r2 '+refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/remotes/r2/*'
  ```

  Now you have two remotes: `origin/master` remembers "`master` as seen on origin, renamed to `origin/master`" and `r2/master` remembers "origin/master as seen on r2 (same URL as origin), renamed to `r2/master`".

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation! I've updated the question to clarify my example. In my case I've already deleted the original repository. I have the remote tracking branches and, as you say can check them out, creating local branches which means the commits exist locally (the point is I still have the code if I ever need it again). I'd just like to transfer those remote tracking branches to another repository.

Comment: Commits just exist, or don't—there's no "local" or "remote" there at all. It's the *names* that have classifications.  I'll add a trick you can use with `git fetch` though.