# "git reset --hard " error unable to stat just-written files after setting "core.bare" to false

Tags: git

When I try the following bash commands:

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/planetoftheweb/learnangular.git .git
git config --bool core.bare false
```

followed by:

```
git reset --hard
```

it gives me this error :

```
error: `unable to stat just-written` file app/component.app.ts: No such file or directory
error: unable to stat just-written file app/component.artist-details.ts: No such file or directory
error: unable to stat just-written file app/component.artist-item.ts: No such file or directory
error: unable to stat just-written file app/pipe.search.ts: No such file or directory
error: unable to stat just-written file app/app.modules.ts: No such file or directory
```

what is the reason?

Answer (score 6):

For others who land here because of the title, but aren't using a bare repo, the following might help. I was in a weird state where I couldn't `reset --hard` due to error:

> error: unable to stat just-written file...

I couldn't `checkout` due to changes.

Here's what worked for me. Note that you'll lose any uncommitted changes. You might like to do a backup of the entire repo before continuing, just in case.

Delete all files and folders in the workspace **except `.git`** then do the following:

```
git checkout -b wat
git add .
git commit -m "WAT"
git checkout master
git branch -D wat
```

Basically this creates a commit on a branch called `wat` that marks every file in the repo as deleted. We then have a clear workspace and can checkout `master` again and delete the useless branch `wat`.

I've just done this and will be keeping an eye on the repo for any further weirdness, and pushing any unpushed branches elsewhere for safety.

Hope this helps someone out one day.

Comment: I wonder whether `git checkout HEAD` would have worked, instead of creating a new branch first. (I just had to do that, because of some MinGW weirdness.)

Comment: I was on `master` when I had the problem, and tried `git checkout master`, but it didn't like the fact the workspace has uncommitted files. Would `HEAD` be different to `master` if that's what I have checked out? Aren't they the same? In my case I couldn't reset the files. In the end, adding them and committing works to clear the workspace, then I could carry on as usual. Haven't had any problems since thankfully.

Comment: There shouldn't be any functional difference there, since `HEAD` and `master` point to the same commit. What I should have said is `git checkout HEAD -- .`, since that would allow overwriting changes  (I think).

In any case, I have sporadic problems with the filesystem under MinGW, so I'll keep this seemingly superfluous cmd sequence in my bag of tricks. Thanks!

Comment: One of the dirty hacks I still use til today and haven't found a better alternative. Is there really no better way to just discard everything I just did? Why do I need to commit my wrong changes first in a trashcan branch, checkout to master and delete the trash. Concretely, is there a better/intended way?

Answer (score 3):

`git clone --bare` makes a bare clone.

`git config --bool core.bare false` tells Git that the bare clone is not a bare clone.  But it still is.  As we used to say about compilers, if you lie to Git, Git will get its revenge.

If you don't want a bare clone, the simplest method is to *not* add `--bare` to your `git clone` command.  If you are dead-set on converting a bare clone to non-bare, see [How do I convert a bare git repository into a normal one (in-place)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10637378/1256452)

Answer (score 3):

For others who land here because of the title, but aren't using a bare repo and don't have [Drew Noakes's issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49701181/205131), the following might help. For me the problem was I cloned a repo in Windows using TortoiseGit that had a filename with a trailing space at the end, `example.png` (<-- there is an extra space after the 'g') instead of `example.png`. I don't think TortoiseGit and/or Windows itself and/or NTFS can handle the trailing space properly. I don't think command line git likes it under Windows either, but I did not investigate that much. In my case the file was not supposed to have the trailing space anyway, so the following git commands in Windows fixed the situation:

```
git mv -f "example.png " example.png
git commit -m "Removed trailing space from filename"
```

I think the file was originally committed under Linux, which apparently does not get as confused with the trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a file named con.sh in my repo, and I was trying to check out this repo on a windows computer. con is the name of an [I/O device](https://superuser.com/questions/86999/why-cant-i-name-a-folder-or-file-con-in-windows) on windows command line, and any file or folder that starts with con conflicts with this device reference. This looks like a bug in both git and windows.

I deleted the local repo folder. Then, I renamed con.sh to connect.sh on a mac and cloned the repo again on windows.

Comment: wow that's bizarre. On windows, in a newly made repo, trying to `git add` a file named con.sh is an infinite operation. Similarly `git mv foo con.sh` incorrectly states the file already exists.

Comment: Yeah, con is the console device "file", so git add is waiting for input from the console. git mv is probably seeing that con I/O "file" exists and is refusing to move it. I would prefer git just skip checking out files that error instead of corrupting the repo state. I would prefer windows not let con.sh conflict with con and/or move con to a root folder like linux's /dev/stdin.