# Converting bare git repository into a copy where I can see the files

Tags: git, git-clone, git-config, git-bare, git-non-bare-repository

I need to convert a local bare git repository to another form where I can see the actual files. My repository is roughly 13.5GB in size. Essentially, the repository is in a state in which it would be if it were hosted on a remote server.

I have a repository structure like the following:

```
- gitrepo
  - repo
    -branches
    -hooks
    -info
    -objects
    -refs
    -HEAD (file)
    -Description (file)
    -config (file)
```

When inspecting the folder in git bash, the `gitrepo` folder is `master`, and the `repo` folder is `BARE:master`.

I understand the `git-clone` command should be used to complete this action, but, when I `git-clone` each of the `gitrepo` and `repo` folders to another directory, I get the message saying I have cloned an empty directory.

Comment: Is [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637378/how-do-i-convert-a-bare-git-repository-into-a-normal-one-in-place) helpful?

Comment: Not quite, I still couldn't see the files. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...