# How to retrieve/restore a GIT repository from bare repo

Tags: git, github, git-bare

Created a bare repository using command "**git clone --bare repo-url**" and deleted the repository from GIT server.

Now i want to retrieve/restore the repository from bare content in my local in windows machine.

What are the steps to be followed?

Comment: navigate to desired location, git clone bare-url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a bare git repository into a normal one (in-place)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637378/how-do-i-convert-a-bare-git-repository-into-a-normal-one-in-place)