# How to download git directory in tar format

Tags: github, tar

Using command "curl -LkSs https://git@github.com:gcce/info.git -o master.tar.gz"
I am expecting to download the info.git directory from github in the master.tar.gz.
However, when I do
"tar -xzvf master.tar.gz" I get error

"gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now"

I have also tried tar -zvf, the error remains there.
Appreciate your response.

Comment: When you run the `curl` command, you are literally just piping the raw output into a file with a `.tar.gz` extension, without actually archiving / compressing it. Open it with VIM or another text editor and I assume you will see plain text. You will need to modify your command to actually do the archive / compression.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a curl of a repo URL won't be useful (and not be compressed)

You need to [download the tarball](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5746376/6309) of a specific version of that repo.

```
curl -L https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs/tarball/v0.24-beta2 | tar zx
```

Note: no need for `git@`. You don't need to specify a user for clone/pull/curl operations on a public repo.